# Regex re.match() not returning match when it should

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, parsing

I'm trying to extract a price from a title of a post and compare it with another price. I found this regular expression pattern: `\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})` that fits my needs perfectly.

I tested it out on https://regexr.com/ and it returns a correct match. however when I try to do that in python 3 I get no matches. here's what the code looks like:

```
def isPriceBetter(CurrentPrice, title):
   r = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})')
   newPrice = r.match(title)

   if newPrice == None:
       return False
   newPrice = float(newPrice)
   if newPrice > CurrentPrice:
       return False
   return True
```

`newPrice` variable is always `None` even though I tested the exact same string that the code is testing on https://regexr.com/ and it returns a match. At first I thought my pattern string was probably being escaped incorrectly which is why I put 'r' in front of the quotes. I've also tried adding more '\' characters but that didn't work either.

Comment: What is an example of a post title you are trying to extract from?

Comment: "[RAM] G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR4 3600mhz $69.99"

Comment: Ah ok. Well in that case `re.match` is going from the beginning of the string. So you either need to account for that by doing `.*?\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2}` or by doing `re.findall` on `\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match` is going to go from the beginning of the string. Because the string does not start with a digit, nothing is going to match. You can instead use something like this:

Assuming `s="[RAM] G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR4 3600mhz $69.99"`

```
In [1]: regex = re.compile('\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})')                                  

In [2]: regex.findall(s)                                                                          
Out[2]: ['69.99']
```

or you need to account for `whatever` is in the beginning of the string and you could create a match `group` like so:

```
In [1]: regex = re.compile('.*?(?P<price>\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2}))')                    

In [2]: match = regex.match(s)                                                                    

In [3]: match                                                                                     
Out[3]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 65), match='[RAM] G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR>

In [4]: match.group('price')                                                                      
Out[4]: '69.99'
```

Comment: ah I see so unlike in other languages re.match() only scans from the beginning of the string. this was quite confusing. thank you for the explanation, I'll just use findall()